# Targets for conditional comments in html?

Tags: html, conditional-comments

I know you can target browsers with conditional comments, as explained [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx).
But I just saw one that looked like this `<!--[if gte mso 9]>`

What does this check for and what (other than browsers) can you check for with conditional comments?

**EDIT**
Is there any documentation on the conditional comments. What options and what version numbers you can use?
mso = Microsoft Outlook
9 = 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This German version of Wikipedia lists the various targets (IE, Microsoft Office, and VML).

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_Comments (You will need to Google translate)

Also, this post suggests that MS Publisher can also be targeted

http://www.adras.com/can-t-view-page-in-browser.t32980-10-2.html

Comment: Ok, so mso and js seem to be the only extra software you can target, besides browsers?

Answer (score 4):

It is used for targeting Microsoft Outlook 2007 and later in HTML emails.  See [this article](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/1774/using-conditional-comments-to-1/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
     1.   <!--[if IE 8]>
        <p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.</p>
        <![endif]-->


      2.  <![if lt IE 8]>
        <p>Please upgrade to Internet Explorer version 8.</p>
        <![endif]>
// include this too
This is <comment>not</comment> Internet Explorer
```

1. firefox - print - nothing

   IE 8 - print - Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.
2. Firefox - print - Please upgrade to Internet Explorer version 8.

   IE 8 - pirnt - nothing but `Welcome to Internet Explorer 8.` if inclcded.

`<!--` comment inner HTML Also while

`<!` will not comment inner HTML. as in FIREFOX example.

Comment: Thank you, but with the risk of sounding ungrateful, that was explained in the link to MSDN. I wanted to know what else you could target beside browsers.

Comment: see `<comment>` as i edit in code and run in firefox & IE and look at this too [wiki][1]             [1]:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment

Comment: one more thing this is specific to micosoft ONly